# Pixelated/Blurry Banner image

Tags: images, image-quality, pixelation

I'm having an issue with a banner image I'm trying to create for my website.

When I upload the image to my website, the icons I added to the banner in Photoshop look blurry. Any advice on how I can avoid this would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: These icons are pixel graphics like PNG or JPG, right? What's their original size in px*px?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. The images appear to have been rescaled.  You can't scale raster images without degradation in quality.